# I added a global variable and also defined it but it gives an error saying window4 is not defined, please can someone clarify?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

```
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.constants import COMMAND
import tkinter as tk
from typing import List


def more():
    OUTPUT_PATH2 = Path(__file__).parent
    ASSETS_PATH2 = OUTPUT_PATH2 / Path("./assets")

    def relative_to_assets5(path: str) -> Path:
        return ASSETS_PATH2 / Path(path)

    window5 = Tk()
    window5.geometry("1440x900")
    window5.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")

    def open_home():
        window5.destroy()
        open_user()
    canvas5 = Canvas(
    window5,
    bg = "#FFFFFF",
    height = 900,
    width = 1440,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
    )
    ftable_3=Frame(canvas5)
    sbHorizontalScrollBar = Scrollbar(window5)
    sbVerticalScrollBar = Scrollbar(window5)

    def updateScrollRegion3():
        canvas5.update_idletasks()
        canvas5.config(scrollregion=ftable_3.bbox())

    def createScrollableContainer3():
        canvas5.config(xscrollcommand=sbHorizontalScrollBar.set,yscrollcommand=sbVerticalScrollBar.set, highlightthickness=0)
        sbHorizontalScrollBar.config(orient=HORIZONTAL, command=canvas5.xview)
        sbVerticalScrollBar.config(orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas5.yview)

        sbHorizontalScrollBar.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM, expand=FALSE)
        sbVerticalScrollBar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT, expand=FALSE)
        canvas5.pack(fill=BOTH, side=LEFT, expand=TRUE)
        canvas5.create_window(0, 0, window=ftable_3, anchor=NW)

    canvas5.bind('<Configure>', lambda _: canvas5.config(scrollregion=canvas5.bbox('all')))
    canvas5.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    background2 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets5("about_us.png"))
    image_3 = canvas5.create_image(
    720.0,
    1608.0,
    image=background2)

    home4 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets5("home.png"))
    home4_ = Button(
    image=home4,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=home_again,
    relief="flat"
    )
    home4_.place(
    x=563.0,
    y=12.0,
    width=144.0,
    height=162.0
    )

    about2 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets5("about.png"))
    about2_ = Button(
    image=about2,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_2 clicked"), 

    relief="flat"
    )
    about2_.place(
    x=720.0,
    y=56.0,
    width=163.0,
    height=80.0
    )

    book_online3 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets5("book.png"))
    book_online3_ = Button(
    image=book_online3,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_3 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    book_online3_.place(
    x=919.0,
    y=56.0,
    width=284.0,
    height=80.0
    )

    more3 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets5("more.png"))
    more3_ = Button(
    image=more3,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_4 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
    )
    more3_.place(
    x=1229.0,
    y=56.0,
    width=122.0,  
    height=80.0
    )

    createScrollableContainer3()
    window5.title('UAC Projects Page')
    window5.resizable(False, False)
    window5.mainloop()

def about_page():
    global window4
    OUTPUT_PATH4 = Path(__file__).parent
    ASSETS_PATH4 = OUTPUT_PATH4 / Path("./assets")
    
    def relative_to_assets4(path: str) -> Path:
        return ASSETS_PATH4 / Path(path)
    
    window4 = Tk()
    window4.geometry("1471x653")
    window4.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")
    canvas4 = Canvas(
        window4,
        bg = "#FFFFFF",
        height = 653,
        width = 1471,
        bd = 0,
        highlightthickness = 0,
        relief = "ridge")
    ftable=Frame(canvas4)
    sbHorizontalScrollBar = Scrollbar(window4)
    sbVerticalScrollBar = Scrollbar(window4)
    def updateScrollRegion2():
        canvas4.update_idletasks()
        canvas4.config(scrollregion=ftable.bbox())

    def createScrollableContainer2():
        canvas4.config(xscrollcommand=sbHorizontalScrollBar.set,yscrollcommand=sbVerticalScrollBar.set, highlightthickness=0)
        sbHorizontalScrollBar.config(orient=HORIZONTAL, command=canvas4.xview)
        sbVerticalScrollBar.config(orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas4.yview)

        sbHorizontalScrollBar.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM, expand=FALSE)
        sbVerticalScrollBar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT, expand=FALSE)
        canvas4.pack(fill=BOTH, side=LEFT, expand=TRUE)
        canvas4.create_window(0, 0, window=ftable, anchor=NW)
    canvas4.bind('<Configure>', lambda _: canvas4.config(scrollregion=canvas4.bbox('all')))
    canvas4.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    background = PhotoImage(file=relative_to_assets4("our_work.png"))
    background1 = canvas4.create_image(
    735.0,
    1457.0,
    image=background
    )
    more =PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets4("more.png"))
    more1 = Button(
        image=more,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_1 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    more1.place(
        x=1244.0,
        y=48.0,
        width=121.0,
        height=88.0
    )
    book_online2 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets4("book.png"))
    book12 = Button(
        image=book_online2,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_2 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    book12.place(
        x=917.0,
        y=34.0,
        width=292.0,
        height=122.0
    )
    about = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets4("about2.png"))
    about1 = Button(
        image=about,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=open_about,
        relief="flat"
    )
    about1.place(
        x=736.0,
        y=16.0,
        width=141.0,
        height=140.0
    )
    home2= PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets4("home2.png"))
    home3 = Button(
        image=home2,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=open_user,
        relief="flat"
    )
    home3.place(
        x=545.0,
        y=8.0,
        width=176.0,
        height=163.0
    )
    createScrollableContainer2()
    window4.title("ABOUT PAGE")
    window4.resizable(False, False)
    window4.mainloop()
      
    

OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path("./assets")

def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)



def user_page():
    global window3
    OUTPUT_PATH3 = Path(__file__).parent
    ASSETS_PATH3 = OUTPUT_PATH3 / Path("./assets")
    
    def relative_to_assets3(path: str) -> Path:
        return ASSETS_PATH3 / Path(path)

    window3 = Tk()
    window3.geometry("1471x653")
    window3.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")
    canvas3 = Canvas(
        window3,
        bg = "#FFFFFF",
        height = 653,
        width = 1471,
        bd = 0,
        highlightthickness = 0,
        relief = "ridge"
    )
    ftable=Frame(canvas3)
    sbHorizontalScrollBar = Scrollbar(window3)
    sbVerticalScrollBar = Scrollbar(window3)
    def updateScrollRegion():
        canvas3.update_idletasks()
        canvas3.config(scrollregion=ftable.bbox())

    def createScrollableContainer():
        canvas3.config(xscrollcommand=sbHorizontalScrollBar.set,yscrollcommand=sbVerticalScrollBar.set, highlightthickness=0)
        sbHorizontalScrollBar.config(orient=HORIZONTAL, command=canvas3.xview)
        sbVerticalScrollBar.config(orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas3.yview)

        sbHorizontalScrollBar.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM, expand=FALSE)
        sbVerticalScrollBar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT, expand=FALSE)
        canvas3.pack(fill=BOTH, side=LEFT, expand=TRUE)
        canvas3.create_window(0, 0, window=ftable, anchor=NW)
    canvas3.bind('<Configure>', lambda _: canvas3.config(scrollregion=canvas3.bbox('all')))
    canvas3.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    background = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets3("background.png"))
    background1 = canvas3.create_image(
    735.0,
    1457.0,
    image=background
    )
    more =PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets3("more.png"))
    more1 = Button(
        image=more,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=open_about_us,
        relief="flat"
    )
    more1.place(
        x=1244.0,
        y=48.0,
        width=121.0,
        height=88.0)
    book_online = PhotoImage(file=relative_to_assets3("book.png"))
    book1 = Button(
        image=book_online,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_2 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    book1.place(
        x=917.0,
        y=34.0,
        width=292.0,
        height=122.0
    )
    about = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets3("about.png"))
    about1 = Button(
        image=about,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=open_about,
        relief="flat"
    )
    about1.place(
        x=736.0,
        y=16.0,
        width=141.0,
        height=140.0
    )
    home= PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets3("home.png"))
    home1 = Button(
        image=home,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_4 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    home1.place(x=545.0,y=8.0,width=176.0,height=163.0)
    createScrollableContainer()
    window3.title("USER PAGE")
    window3.resizable(False, False)
    window3.mainloop()
      
def admin_page():    
    from pathlib import Path
    from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage
    from tkinter.constants import COMMAND


    OUTPUT_PATH2 = Path(__file__).parent
    ASSETS_PATH2 = OUTPUT_PATH2 / Path("./assets")


    def relative_to_assets2(path: str) -> Path:
        return ASSETS_PATH2 / Path(path)


    window2 = Tk()
    window2.geometry("1190x708")
    window2.configure(bg = "#000000")

    canvas2 = Canvas(
        window2,
        bg = "#000000",
        height = 708,
        width = 1190,
        bd = 0,
        highlightthickness = 0,
        relief = "ridge"
    )

    canvas2.place(x = 0, y = 0)
    canvas2.create_rectangle(
        18.0,
        177.0,
        1178.0,
        687.0,
        fill="#000000",
        outline="white",width=5)

    enter = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets2("enter.png"))
    enter_button = Button(
        image=enter,
        borderwidth=0,
        highlightthickness=0,
        command=lambda: print("button_1 clicked"),
        relief="flat"
    )
    enter_button.place(
        x=707.0,
        y=591.0,
        width=151.0,
        height=62.0
    )

    entry_image_1 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets2("entry_1.png"))
    entry_bg_1 = canvas2.create_image(
        819.0,
        515.5,
        image=entry_image_1
    )
    entry_1 = Entry(
        bd=0,
        bg="#000000",
        highlightthickness=5,
        fg='white',
        font=("Montserrat",33),
        show='*',
    )
    entry_1.place(
        x=513.0,
        y=470.0,
        width=612.0,
        height=89.0
    )

    canvas2.create_text(
        513.0,
        370.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="PASSWORD",
        fill="#FFFFFF",
        font=("Oswald Regular", 72 * -1)
    )

    entry_image_2 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets2("entry_2.png"))
    entry_bg_2 = canvas2.create_image(
        823.0,
        324.5,
        image=entry_image_2
    )
    entry_2 = Entry(
        bd=0,
        bg="#000000",
        highlightthickness=5,
        fg='white',
        font=("Montserrat",33),
    )
    entry_2.place(
        x=517.0,
        y=279.0,
        width=612.0,
        height=89.0
    )

    canvas2.create_text(
        513.0,
        177.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="USERNAME",
        fill="#FFFFFF",
        font=("Oswald Regular", 72 * -1)
        )

    logo2 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets2("logo2.png"))
    logo2_ = canvas2.create_image(
        229.0,
        424.0,
        image=logo2
    )

    canvas2.create_rectangle(
        493.0,
        177.0,
        501.0,
        687.0,
        fill="#FFFDFD",
        outline="")

    canvas2.create_text(
        150.0,
        48.0,
        anchor="nw",
        text="SYSTEM   ACCESS  :   LOGIN",
        fill="#FFFFFF",
        font=("Oswald Regular", 72 * -1)
    )

    logo3 = PhotoImage(
        file=relative_to_assets2("logo3.png"))
    image_2 = canvas2.create_image(
        80.0,
        90.0,
        image=logo3
    )
    window2.resizable(False, False)
    window2.title("UAC SYSTEM ACCESS PAGE")
    window2.mainloop()
window = Tk()

window.geometry("1190x708")
window.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")

def open_admin():
    window.destroy()
    admin_page()    
   
def open_user():
    window.destroy()
    user_page()

def open_about():
    window3.destroy()
    about_page()

def open_about_us():
    window3.destroy()
    more()
def home_again():
    window4.destroy()
    user_page()


window.resizable(False, False)

canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#FFFFFF",
    height = 708,
    width = 1190,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)


canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("planet1.png"))
image_1_create = canvas.create_image(
    601.0,
    350.0,
    image=image_1
)


image_image_2 = PhotoImage(file=relative_to_assets("logo.png"))
image_2 = canvas.create_image(186.0, 220.0,image=image_image_2)

canvas.create_text(283.0, 137.0, anchor="nw", text="U", fill="#A42222", font=("Roboto BlackItalic", 72 * -1))

canvas.create_text(330.0, 137.0, anchor="nw", text="nion", fill="#FFFFFF", font=("Roboto BlackItalic", 72 * -1))

canvas.create_text(503.0, 137.0, anchor="nw", text="A", fill="#A42222", font=("Roboto BlackItalic", 72 * -1))

canvas.create_text(551.0, 137.0, anchor="nw", text="erospace", fill="#FFFFFF", font=("Roboto BlackItalic", 72 * -1))

canvas.create_text(400.0, 230.0, anchor="nw", text="C", fill="#A42222", font=("Roboto BlackItalic", 72 * -1))

canvas.create_text(447.0, 230.0, anchor="nw", text="orporation", fill="#FFFFFF", font=("Roboto BlackItalic", 72 * -1))

canvas.create_text(10.0, 671.0, anchor="nw", text="© 2153 Weyland-Yutani", fill="#FFFFFF", font=("Roboto", 24 * -1))

button_image_1 = PhotoImage(file=relative_to_assets("admin.png"))
button_1 = Button(image=button_image_1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, command=open_admin, relief="flat")
button_1.place(x=432.0, y=500.0, width=145.0,height=75.0)

button_image_2 = PhotoImage(file=relative_to_assets("user.png"))
button_2 = Button(image=button_image_2, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, command=open_user, relief="flat")
button_2.place(x=449.0, y=388.0, width=120.0, height=62.0)

window.resizable(False, False)
window.title("Union Aerospace Corporation")

window.mainloop()
```

Here, I have added all the code to open a window, and i want the window4 to be destroyed, but when i do this, the program tells me it is not defined, even tho i have defined it as a global variable and have also defined it as a window.
You don't have to look at the whole code, just the def home_again() and the about_page() functions since that's where the error is, i've added the whole code in case you had any doubts in how the code is going.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to test this because its not a MWE. Since you define the global variable in a function, it is likely you are trying the use the global variable before the function is called.